# Is it safe to initialize a member using a member initialized earlier in initializer list?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, undefined-behavior

Is the following code safe or does it lead to undefined behavior in C++03?

```
class Aries {
public:
    Aries() : Taurus("foo") , Leo(Taurus + "bar") {}

private:
    string Taurus;
    const string Leo;
};
```

This code is obviously a stripped down version of my actual problem.

**Edit** `Taurus` has been intentionally declared before `Leo` in the class declaration. I am aware the initialization happens in the order of initialization in class declaration (not the order in the initializer list.)

Comment: That code has safe, well-defined behavior, but only because `Taurus` is _declared_ first.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, I am aware of that initialization happens in the order of declaration in class, not the order in the initializer list. Thanks for bringing that out.

Comment: While safe, I would not recommend it.  Some comments near the variable declarations would be very good.

Comment: This is a rough spot in C++. With non-default-constructible classes (or when constructing with the proper value is just better), when the initializer is too much for a one-liner, sometimes you just have to code this way and clarify what's happening with comments. Or use a factory function with a perhaps private constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify an alternative I mentioned in the comments:

```
class Aries {
public:
    friend Aries makeAries() {
        string Taurus = "foo"; // easier to do computations here:
        return Aries( Taurus, Taurus + "bar" );
    }

private:
    Aries( string const &inTaurus, string const &inLeo )
        : Taurus(inTaurus) , Leo(inLeo) {}

    string Taurus;
    const string Leo;
};
Aries makeAries(); // must declare a friend factory outside the class
```

This isn't a universal solution or a really desirable idiom, but can still be helpful and relatively clean.

Comment: As you have mentioned, it is not universally applicable, but this is certainly a good idiom to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can safely use members that are initialized before the member you are initializing.

Note that the order of initialization is the order of declaration in the class definition.

Comment: +1 for the note about where the initialization order comes from.